# Uploaded Image is not stored in directory in spring

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to upload an image and save it to a specific folder. This is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/echofile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> echoFile(HttpServletRequest  request, HttpSession session,
                HttpServletResponse response ,  @ModelAttribute("uploadedFile") UploadedFile upldfile) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

         if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){

               InputStream inputStream = null;
                  OutputStream outputStream = null;
                MultipartFile multipartFile = ((MultipartRequest) request).getFile("file");

                MultipartFile file = upldfile.getFile();
                String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

                System.out.println("filename:"+fileName);
                upldfile.setFile(file);
                String fileName2 = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                System.out.println("filename2:"+fileName2);

                Long size = multipartFile.getSize();
                String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
                InputStream stream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);


                map.put("fileoriginalsize", size);
                map.put("contenttype", contentType);
                map.put("base64", new String(Base64Utils.encode(bytes)));

                try {
                      // inputStream = ((MultipartFile) upldfile).getInputStream();

                    inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                        String webRootDir = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        String url = "E:/Java_Project/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/src/main/webapp/resources/image";

                        String pathFl = url + File.separator ;
                       File newFile = new File(webRootDir+pathFl+fileName);
                       if (!newFile.exists()) {
                        newFile.createNewFile();
                       }
                       outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                       int read = 0;
                      // byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                       while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                       }
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                      }


            }

         return map;
     }

This is my JS ajax part:

var isJpg = function(name) {
    return name.match(/jpg$/i)
};

    var isPng = function(name) {
        return name.match(/png$/i)
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var file = $('[name="file"]');
        var imgContainer = $('#imgContainer');

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            var filename = $.trim(file.val());

            if (!(isJpg(filename) || isPng(filename))) {
                alert('Please browse a JPG/PNG file to upload ...');
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/echofile",
                type: "POST",
                //data: formData,
                data: new FormData(document.getElementById("fileForm")),
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                modelAttribute:'uploadedFile',
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    imgContainer.html('');
                    //var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    var img = '<img src="data:' + data.contenttype + ';base64,'
                    + data.base64 + '"/>';

                    alert("success");
                    imgContainer.append(img);
                },

                error: function(){                      
                    alert('Error while request..');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But When I input an image, ajax alert me success, but image is not shown in `div` and also I have given a path to save the image on that folder (specific directory) but image is not saved in that folder. What I should do?

[image: Inspects shows the error]

Comment: You shouldn't be storing uploaded files inside your web app, great change that on your next deployment those files are gone.  Next to that the String used as `url` is also wrong. On deployment there is no `src/main/` etc. So not sure what kind of path you are constructing but looks like not something useable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var byteCharacters = atob(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, ''));
                            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters
                                        .charCodeAt(i);
                            }
                            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                            var blob = new Blob([ byteArray ], {
                                type : undefined

   @RequestMapping(value = "shippingcustomer/{id}/uploadpancard", method =               RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ServiceStatus> UploadPanCard(@PathVariable("id") Long scId,
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpSession session) {
    try {
        shippingCustomerService.uploadPancard(scId, request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<ServiceStatus>    (ServiceStatus.PAN_CARD_UPLOADED,
            HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

 @Override
public void uploadPancard(Long scId, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        ShippingCustomer sc = findShippingCustomer(scId);
        if (sc != null) {
            Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                List<ImageInfo> imgs = ImageInfo
                        .findImageInfoesByImageTypeAndEntityIdEqualsAndImageInfoType(
                                DocumentType.PANCARD, scId, ImageInfoType.SC)
                        .getResultList();
                for (ImageInfo imageInfo : imgs) {
                    imageInfo.remove();
                }
                MultipartFile file = request.getFile(itr.next());
                ImageInfo img = new ImageInfo();
                img.setImage(file.getBytes());
                img.setEntityId(scId);
                img.setImageInfoType(ImageInfoType.SC);
                img.setImageType(DocumentType.PANCARD);
                img.persist();
            }
        } else {
            throw new ShippingCustomerNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text to explain your answer. Thanks.